# how to call a method in custom Directive from custom services click event in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

MY project having custom services body binded to click event, when clicked on body in service need to call resetDropdown() function in custom directive. how can i do please help me bro?

```
I tried code bellow that is first one is custom directive contain method.
```

.directive('dropdownMenu', ['$parse', '$compile', 'DropdownService', '$templateCache',
    function ($parse, $compile, DropdownService, $templateCache) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        ngTransclude:true,
        scope: {
          dropdownMenu: '=',
          dropdownModel: '=',
          dropdownItemLabel: '@',
          dropdownOnchange: '&',
          dropdownDisabled: '=',
          dropdownSubmit: '&'
        },

```
  $scope.resetDropdown = function(){
              alert("calling reset Dropdown by me");
          }
}
```

});
    next custom service having code 
    .factory('DropdownService', ['$document',
        function ($document, $rootScope, $scope) {
          var body = $document.find('body'),

```
      body.bind('click', function (event, $scope, $rootScope) {
            resetDropdown();
    });
    when body clicked resetDropdown method need to call how can i do please help me.
```

Comment: how to call method in directive from service when clicked samthing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is required. But your directive method is in $scope and you are trying to call method in $rootScope.

Comment: update code can you check once, when click on body, needs to call resetDropdwon() function but not calling ,how can i call , please help me any one

Comment: hello please help me

Comment: Please paste code in good format... its hard to understand. and please elaborate your problem a bit more. like what you want to achieve

Comment: Your directive is having its own isolated scope, so whatever method you will write in directive controller will be available only in its isolated scope.